# Insert Into Using OpenQuery Causes Massive Fragmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, fragmentation

I use the following code to import a table from an Oracle DB to SQL Server every day:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable

INSERT INTO mytable (firstname, lastname, city, state)
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (mylinkedserver, 'SELECT firstname, lastname, 
city, state FROM mylinkedtable')
```

The above causes massive fragmentation (90% to 99%) on my nonclustered indexes on "mytable".  If I run the below code

```
SELECT * INTO mytesttable
FROM mytable

TRUNCATE TABLE mytable

INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT * FROM mytesttable

DROP TABLE mytesttable
```

I end up with fragmentation of between 1% and 3% on my nonclustered indexes.  What is causing this?  Both statements are truncating the table and inserting new data into a blank table.

Comment: What indexes exist in the top version? How many pages are created? Is it possible you're worried about fragmentation for nothing?

Comment: For example, please have a good read through this, and make sure that you're looking at numbers other than just fragmentation percent. If you've loaded 100 pages onto disk, fragmentation is absolutely 100% irrelevant. http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/